# jquery - working with variables?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a variable:

```
var $box = $(this).next('widget');
```

Now say I want to make another div inside the widget div fade out. How can I can be able to access that div inside the box variable?

Answer (score 4):

```
var $box = $(this).next('widget');

$box.find('#your_div').fadeOut(); // #your_div is just a selector, 
                                  // you may have something different
```